# Line extracted from text not matching the content of the text array

Tags: python, text, readfile

I have this block of code:

```
    def removal(i):
    with open(r"D:\Largecodefile\Customer.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    h,j = i-2,i-1
    data1, data2 = lines[h],lines[j]
    print('data is ',data1,'and',data2)
    print('line is ',lines)
    with open(r"D:\Largecodefile\Customer.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip('\n') != data1 and data2:
                f.write(line)
```

I'm trying to make it rewrite the file and exclude the specific line that I choose. As of right now, my line output is:

```
line is  ['JSJSJSJSJS\n', '10-02-1975\n', 'HAHAHAHAHA\n', '26-11-2001\n', 'BOTBOITBOT\n', '13-09-2018\n', 'Phill\n', 'Gill']
```

and data1 and data 2 is:

```
data is  Phill\n and Gill
```

They seem matchup to the list from I what see, however, the system is not recognizing it, I think the problem is at the second last line of the code but I can't make it work. Is it that I went wrong somewhere? Thank you!

Edit: Hi, it's me again, I just want to add that I've tried using 1 data to excluded it too and see if it works, `if line.strip('\n') != data1:` but sadly the result is still the same, I tried removing \n either, not reccomended but I did it anyway, does not get affected too

Comment: Hi, I edited my reply to better represent what you tried to do. Let me know if it's ok

Comment: Let's say you select a line from the file that contains 'Gill'. Is it your intention to remove **all** lines that are equal to 'Gill' or just the two adjacent lines (i-2 and i-1) that you originally chose. If it's the latter case then there is no need for string comparisons

Comment: Hi @OldBill, it's the latter case that I intended to choose, but thanks to you I've just figured out the flaws in it now. However, can you please let me know why the string comparison did not get the right result for the code above? I've been thinking about it but I can't understand why

Comment: @V21 This is wrong -> *if line.strip('\n') != data1 and data2*. Should be *if line.strip('\n') != data1 and line.strip('\n') != data2*. But that's not the right way to do it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a syntax mistake. You are checking if line is not equal to data1, and if data2 is True:

```
if line.strip('\n') != data1 and data2:
```

solution (check if line also is not equal to data2):

```
if line != data1 and line != data2:
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this explained it well also. I've got confused between the line.strip('\n') and the comparison logic but your answer summed it up perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you strip the incoming file as you build a list of lines. splitlines on a string is ideal for this.

If you use open mode r+ there's no need to open the file twice. Just seek to BOF after consuming the file content and remember to call truncate before closing.

```
def removal(i):
    with open(r"D:\Largecodefile\Customer.txt", 'r+', newline='') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        h, j = i-2, i-1
        # validation here is critical
        if h >= 0 and j < len(lines):
            data1, data2 = lines[h], lines[j]
            f.seek(0) # BOF
            for line in lines:
                if not line in {data1, data2}:
                    print(line, file=f) # print will add the newline
            f.truncate()
```